# Core algorithm of genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

What is core algorithm of the genetic algorithm? 
What needs to be defined precisely in order to code the algorithm?

Comment: The genetic algorithm is the core algorithm of the genetic algorithm. Love recursion:P

Comment: this question is related to AI, heuristics etc.

Comment: This is a real question, albeit a not very good one (it's homework and easily googlable). Someone incorrectly edited it though, changing "genetic" to "generic".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define:

1. The **encoding** for a solution (e.g. bitstring, tree, etc)
2. The **fitness function** - how to quantitatively evaluate the "goodness" of a solution
3. The **crossover operator** - a binary function that takes two parent solutions and combines them into a child solution
4. The **mutation operator** - a unary function that takes a solution and makes a small change (i.e. mutation) to it
5. **Selection** - how do you select individuals for the next generation? This includes the probabilities associated with crossover and mutation.

Comment: Giving the answer to a homework question only encourages that person not to do their homework and [continue asking homework questions without showing effort.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899912/ai-question-on-machine-learning)